# How to allocate memory with python using pointers? byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not 'int'

Tags: python, memory, ctypes

I'm trying to make a C++ program work in python but I'm having a problem with the `ZeroMemory` macro from the windows api.
This is the C++ code:

```
char Data[512]; 
SecureZeroMemory(&Data, (sizeof Data));
```

and this is the python code that I tried but it gave an error "byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not 'int' :

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

Data = wintypes.CHAR
Data = 512
ctypes.memset(ctypes.byref(Data), ctypes.sizeof(Data))
```

Here is the link to the microsoft documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa366920(v=vs.85)

Comment: Shouldn't it be like a `ctypes.size_t` or something else from `ctypes`, and not just a bare Python `int`? Setting `Data = wintypes.CHAR` does absolutely nothing at all, since you're just completely erasing that and replacing `Data`'s value with an `int` on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to zero memory allocated by `ctypes`.  New instances are zeroed by default:

```py
import ctypes
data = (ctypes.c_char * 10)()  # equivalent to char data[10]; in C++
data[4] = 0x55
print(data.raw.hex())
```

Output:

```
00000000550000000000
```

But if you are just *porting* C++ to Python you don't need `ctypes` at all.  It is used for interfacing Python code to C++ code.

If you need a writable byte buffer in Python, you can use `bytearray`:

```py
import ctypes
data = bytearray(10)
data[4] = 0x55
print(data.hex())
```

Output:

```
00000000550000000000
```

To use `ctypes.memset` correctly, it takes 3 parameters: a `ctypes` object address, the value to set, and the size.  Arrays pass their address by default so no need for `ctypes.byref` unless passing the address of a scalar such as `ctypes.c_int`:

```py
import ctypes

data = (ctypes.c_char * 10)(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
print(data.raw.hex())
ctypes.memset(data, 0, ctypes.sizeof(data))
print(data.raw.hex())

num = ctypes.c_int(0x55) # 4-byte integer.
print(hex(num.value))
ctypes.memset(ctypes.byref(num), 0x12, ctypes.sizeof(num))
print(hex(num.value))
```

Output:

```
0102030405060708090a
00000000000000000000
0x55
0x12121212
```